# Reading Configurations using Argparse

Tags: python-3.x, file, parsing, argparse

In a separate configuration file, I have the following:

```
charge 0
```

In my program, I am trying to use argparse so that I can read some configurations from another file. However, the output is something like this:

```
Namespace(charge='charge 0')
```

How should I write my add_argument or parse_args in order to exclude the word "charge" in my value?

Comment: How are you reading this file?  With the `fromfile_prefix_chars` mechanism?    It might help if you showed a basic working `parser`.

Comment: I used these 3 lines:

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@') parser.add_argument('charge', metavar='Charge', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

Comment: You've defined a `positional`, which takes 1 string.  The default `@` reader gets 1 string from each line of the file.  The effect is the same as if you'd given a commandline with `prog.py "charge 0"`.  You'll have to process the string yourself after parsing.

Comment: The docs also have a short section on customizing the prefix file reader.

Comment: As far as parsing strings go, would this be using another module, or would it be possible to use argparse?

Comment: There is  config parser module.  Also look at `pyyaml`.

Comment: I found a convert_arg_line_to_args, but I'm not sure how to override the function...

Comment: The way the `fromfile...` method is intended to be used is like putting your command line options in a file. On the command line you wouldn't call `prog.py charge 0`, you would just call `prog.py 0`.  In the same way, if you just put `0` in the file it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to omit 'charge' in your file, then subclass `ArgumentParser` and override [`convert_arg_line_to_args`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.convert_arg_line_to_args).

```
import argparse

class MyArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):

    def convert_arg_line_to_args(self, arg_line):
        """Remove the label from a given argument."""
        try:
            return arg_line.split()[1:]  # given 'charge 0', returns ['0']
        except IndexError:
            return arg_line.split()  # Only one element, just return in a list.
```